# Cucumber-jvm Either the specified parameters do not match any of the following constructors: [private java.lang.Class()];

Tags: java, android, bdd, cucumber-jvm, picocontainer

I am testing a simple Cucumber BDD test on Android and getting a cucumber error

```
org.picocontainer.PicoCompositionException: Either the specified 
parameters do not match any of the following constructors: [private 
java.lang.Class()]; OR the constructors were not accessible for 
'java.lang.Class'
```

I cannot figure out where this error is coming from.
Am I missing something ?

My feature file

```
Scenario Outline: Test scenario
    Given I have a TestActivity
    Then I should see <text> on the display

Examples:
    | text |
    | 123  |
    | test |
```

Step definition

```
@CucumberOptions(features = "features", format = "pretty")
public class TestActivitySteps extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<TestActivity> {

    public TestActivitySteps(Class<TestActivity> activityClass) {
        super(activityClass);
    }

    @Given("^I have a TestActivity$")
    public void I_have_a_TestActivity() {
        assertNotNull(getActivity());
    }

    @Then("^I should see (\\S+) on the display$")
    public void I_should_see_s_on_the_display(final String s) {
        onView(withText(s)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
}
```

NOTE:

- Android Studio: 1.0.2
- Gradle: 2.2.1
- Cucumber: 1.2.0
- Espresso: 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out.  This constructor was triggering the error.

```
public TestActivitySteps(Class<TestActivity> activityClass) {
    super(activityClass);
}
```

The error was gone after I changed to

```
public TestActivitySteps(TestActivity activityClass) {
    super(activityClass);
}
```